# Differences in developing for IOS and Android (Unity)

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am planning to develop a game both for Android and for IOS. My engine of choice is Unity as it is supposed to support both OSs. Is there going to be any difference at all in the development phase? For example, should I consider the OS in things like storing data like high score, or in things like input type? Or does unity provide an abstraction level for these things, and takes care of everything in the build phase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you make a game in unity you can deploy that on many platform without doing any significant changes. However there will be sometime when you will need some part of your code only run on some specific platform, which you can do like [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html). Regarding saving data, this may depend on how you want to implement things in your code. You can use playerpref which is supported on all platforms or you can use third party sdk. I think this may have cleared your doubt.

Answer (score 2):

A quote from the Unity website:

> There are so many platforms you can deploy to with the Unity game engine, and their number is growing all the time. Build your content once and deploy at a click across all major mobile, desktop and console platforms plus the Web. Use the official Facebook SDK for Unity to integrate cross-platform games with ease, experiment with the Oculus Rift and more.